# Why result of find command in linux is unsorted?

Tags: linux, find

When I do a `find` the results are apparently in random order, shouldn't they be sorted by name?

Comment: They actually are sorted. Just not alphabetically, but by their place in the file tree...

Comment: @Kwaio Are they sorted with inode numbers?

Comment: I'm not familliar with inode assignment but I think not. Just imagine you're doing a deep-first search over a tree, going alphabetically as the second sorting order. that's what you get.

Answer (score 5):

To return sorted results, `find` would have to find *everything* before it could output *anything*. That would make things much, much slower. If you need the results sorted, you can easily sort them by piping the output of `find` to `sort`.

Comment: Piping the output into a separate sorting tool (like but not necessarily `sort`) also allows for any number of possible sort algorithms to be used. If it was built into `find` then you'd be stuck with what `find` offers *or* **still** need that separate sorting tool.

Comment: I actually know how to sort, but just curious why the result is not sorted, I think this need to investigate what method find use to find files.

Comment: It would not need to sort everything. `find` would only have to sort each directory before iterating over its contents for the results to be sorted. / `ls` is slower than `find` simply because it does sort the directories after reading them but before listing them. / The cause is that on file systems with unordered indexes for directories, the entries read need not be returned in sorted order, unlike how DOS and its FAT did.